# Need to read location.txt vs Tableau and process lines with '&' as a string, not escape in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

I have been playing around with a code my colleague sent me, Here is the issue I am running into.
This code logs me into Tableau and runs the names of certain locations against my Tableau sheet & if it finds a matching name in the LOCATION.txt it PDFs that locations information off of Tableau into my AutomatePars folder. WORKS AMAZING for all locations EXCEPT the locations who's names contain an &
The names of all the locations are pulled from a separate text file (the locations I am interested change all the time) and all spaces are already removed.

I NEED to read in each name as a string even when they have "&" in them. I can't escape or forget the & because the name of the location has an '&' in it...I have tried escaping and I get the same null read in my PDF....very frustrating for sure.
Another colleague suggested creating some other variable & then using replace, but I have no idea how to do that...any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure how to fix this!

```
@echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)
set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%
set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%-%CUR_MM%-%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
if exist C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%CUR_YYYY%-%CUR_MM%-%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS% RMDIR /s /Q C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%CUR_YYYY%-%CUR_MM%-%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
md "C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%SUBFILENAME%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\LOCATION.txt) do call :processline %%a
rem using the live database, add “?:refresh=yes” after the URL in order to get the latest snapshot as an output.

    :processline
    tabcmd export "ParForm/ParLevelSheet?Location=%*&:refresh=yes" --pdf --pagelayout landscape --pagesize unspecified -f "C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%SUBFILENAME%\%*.pdf" -t "Moda"
    if EXIST "C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%SUBFILENAME%\.pdf" DEL /F "C:\Users\USER\Automate_Pars\%SUBFILENAME%\.pdf"
    echo "complete"
```

Comment: Use quotes to protect the special characters`call :processline "%%a"`. You are also missing a `GOTO` or `EXIT` within your code. Your existing code will run everything below your label one extra time because you are not exiting the program or skipping over it.

Comment: Should I just add an EXIT at then end of the code to make sure I don't run more than once then?

Comment: Think of `:ProcessLine` as a function.  But in batch file scripting it really isn't aware that it is a function like `BASH` or even `Vbscripts`.  You only want `:Processline` to execute when called so that means you need to use a `GOTO` or `EXIT` before the function starts.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can offer is to work it into a global variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
Set "ESC=^"
Set "PrepareVal=text%%ESC%%&other"
CALL :function text%%ESC%%^&other
ECHO Done.
pause
exit

:function
Set "ParamVal=%1"
ECHO !ParamVal!
CALL "%userprofile%\desktop\RecArg.bat"
ECHO Returned
GOTO :EOF
```

Recieving .bat

```
@Echo OFF
ECHO passed as Variable.
ECHO !ParamVal!
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

Passing the variable as an argument fails.